# loop value in format time(hour and minute)

Tags: javascript, loops

How to display the value, using for loop in JavaScript?

ex: if i loop number 0 < 2 then i get result like this:

```
0
1
```

my question how i make the loop like this:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
to
0:59 
1:0
1:1
1:2
1:3
1:4
to
1:59
```

because the last loop is `1`,how i make  `+1` so the last loop result like this:

```
    0:0
    0:1
    0:2
    0:3
    0:4
    to
    0:59 
    1:0
    1:1
    1:2
    1:3
    1:4
    to
    1:59
    2:0
```

thank you

Comment: Use a nested loop, where the outer loop does the minutes and the inner loop does the seconds. Or are you saying you can do it in a general sense but you don't know how to get it to stop at `2:0` rather than `1:59`?

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) a couple of ways of doing this.

Perhaps the easiest would be to have two nested loops, one for the minute and one for the second, along the lines of the following pseudo-code:

```
for minutes = 0 to 59 inclusive:
    for seconds = 0 to 59 inclusive:
        output minutes ":" seconds
```

That won't necessarily scale well as you move up to hours and days and it means you have to work on a minute-boundary. In other words, you can't easily do 752 seconds (12m32s) unless you do some monstrosity like:

```
for minutes = 0 to 11 inclusive:
    for seconds = 0 to 59 inclusive:
        output minutes ":" seconds
for seconds = 0 to 32 inclusive:
    output "12:" seconds
```

Perhaps a better way, which alleviates those problems,would be to work *exclusively* with seconds and *translate* that to more complete units on the fly:

```
for fullsecs = 0 to 752 inclusive:
    secsleft = fullsecs

    seconds = fullsecs % 60
    secsleft = secsleft - seconds

    minutes = (secsleft / 60) % 60
    secsleft = secsleft - minutes * 60

    hours = (secsleft / 3600) % 24
    secsleft = secsleft - hours * 3600

    days = secsleft / 86400

    output days ":" hours ":" minutes ":" seconds
```

What that snippet within the loop does is to strip out the "odd" seconds (those that aren't a multiple of a minute) and then subtract those seconds from the value, so that the result *is* a multiple of a minute.

Then it does that, for other units as well, all the way up to days, using the fact that there are `60` seconds in a minute, `60 * 60 = 3600` in an hour, and `24 * 60 * 60 = 86400` in a day.